# How can I test if the standard input starts with a certain word?

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to parse some input files that can come in two different versions. I need to be able to deduce the file format as I am parsing the files.

The first version is just a list of numbers, one per line:

```
123
456
789
```

The second type of file has two numbers per line and a line at the top marking it as the newest version of the file format

```
#version 2
123 10
456 20
789 30
```

What is the **simplest** way to test it the file I am reading starts with a `"#version N"` line? If the version line is there I want to consume it and if its not then I don't want to consume any characters in the input stream.

The problem is that I think I need some way to unread characters and I only know of ungetc, which only works for a single character and not for a whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you read the file, you can set your pointers back to the original position.

C provides `fseek` to change the position of file pointers. Once you read the file and found that it is of different version, you can use `fseek` to set the pointer at beginning so that next read starts from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your problem.  It seems like all you need is `ungetc()` because you can skip over whitespace until you see either a digit or a `#` and then you will know which file is which.  Yet you feel you need more, and I don't know why you feel that way.

You could write a "tokenizer" that parses the input into tokens, and then make your processing code consume the tokens.  Then you can "rewind" simply by looking at the first token pointer again.

This is a nice division of labor: you can make your tokenizer handle skipping whitespace, skipping comments, and even do things like handle `#include` directives.  You could read a line, have the tokenizer split it on white space, and pass pointers to each word in the line to be consumed by the rest of the code.

Or you could use `malloc()` to allocate a buffer for each token from the input if you want the program to be as flexible as possible.  I have written simple compilers this way, because I wanted to be able to "rewind" at the tokens level to see what came before something else.  The input file was converted to a linked list of tokens and I was able to look before and after the current token to try to figure things out from context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know that each text file is going to have `#version x` (where x is the number) at the top of the file. You could do a simple fscanf to determine the version number and then call a function to handle that type of version:

```
/* where 'str' is a char[] and 'version' is an int */
fscanf(pfile, "%s %d", str, &version)

if (version == 1) {
    /* Handle version 1 */
}
if (version == 2) {
    /* Handle version 2 */
}
```

Comment: The "version 1" files do not have a line at the top. They are just a list of nmbers